# Issues with uploading apk on Google Play Store

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have a app on Google play store.
I want to put it update  version on play store.For that i have just incremented app version code from AndroidManifest.xml.And upload that version on Google play store.
All is going fine and my app uploaded successfully on store.

What the updated version is not showing so far instead the old application is appearing.

So how much time it take to get upload perfectly so that users got the updated version.?

Comment: Fot how long your newer version is uploaded there? Usually google ps takes  two to four hours to update everything. And did u published the updated version or no?

Comment: How long it has been uploaded there?

Comment: it takes nearly 10 minutes

Comment: well thats tooo early to complain :) .. Wait couple of hours usually two hours to four and you will receive an update from google play store. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes 3-4 hrs to update an application in google playstore.wait for couple of hours,you will get it.All the best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally its takes 3-4 hour for an app to get updated. But some times it may take more then that due to more traffic.